# How to query moves in the Opening Book (.obk) of Xiangqi (Chinese Chess)

Tags: algorithm, hash, chess

I'm creating a Xianqi GUI to read Opening Books ( .obk ), I'm stuck on the step how to get the moves from books that matching with current positions of pieces on the board, in books every the moves has a **vkey** like "7101337512282506414" (first state of positions of pieces on the board ) or "19018984774421643", "-5, 90534042772364e+ 293", .etc... (others state of positions of pieces on the board).
I'm trying to find the exact source code that handles the hash algorithm. Could you guys help me with solutions or keywords to research?

Here is what my .obk file looks like:
[opening book of Xiangqi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgtl5.png)

I found some source code on Github, Youtube. But their results are different from what I expected.

On Github:
Like https://github.com/fairy-stockfish/bookgen, https://bookgen-wasm.vercel.app/
The result are "CF494C075A7D927E", it is not matching with "7101337512282506414"

[fairy-stockfish bookgen hashing key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxYlJ.png)

Or on Youtube:
Xiangqi chess engine in javascript: Zobrist hashing
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LtZXdwSth-c

Thanks for reading.